# Problems with a slash command that sends quotes as embeds - "expected an object and received string instead" - I'm using javascript and discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a discord slash command that sends funny quotes, taking one random value from 3 different arrays respectively (a quote, an author and an image) and then putting together a discord embed with those 3 values. There's also this other number that's randomly selected from 1 to 1000 that's later included into the embed's footer.

The issue itself was encountered when I debugged the file and used the slash command "deep-quote". The discord bot didn't respond, and the following message appeared in the debug console:

> "expected an object and received string instead"

I'm not really sure why it needs an object to run the command to be honest, and why a string isn't considered one.

I've tried declaring variables outside the functions that return random numbers, this was done to like "trick" the machine lol, but I suppose it really doesn't do much. I've also tried changing Discord.EmbedBuilder() to Discord.MessageEmbed to see if something would change, but the only thing that changed was the error message, now saying "Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor".

Here's the code:

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if(interaction.isCommand()) {

      if (interaction.commandName === "deep-quote") {
        // compNumb is a function that returns a random number from 1 to 1000
        function compNumb() {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        }
        // getQuote should return a random number that works accordingly with the quote's array length
        function getQuote() {
          let randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
          return randomQuote;
        }
        // getCredit should return a random number that works accordingly with the credit's array length
        function getCredit() {
          let randomCredit = Math.floor(Math.random() * credit.length);
          return randomCredit;
        }
        // getQuoteImage should return a random number that works accordingly with the imageQuote's array length
        function getQuoteImage() {
          let randomQuoteImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageQuote.length);
          return randomQuoteImage;
        }
      
        // I tried declaring the following variables to the functions that return a random number; I thought that since the issue is dealing with objects, -
        // -I could declare variables that are in the end a number and use that, but I'm not even sure what an object is.
        let Author = getCredit();
        let theQuote = getQuote();
        let compNumber = compNumb();
        let epicQuoteImage = getQuoteImage();
      
        // Here I replace some of the values of the embed's properties to the variables that I declared, that end up calling a function that return a number
        let quoting = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
          .setAuthor(credit[Author])
          .setTitle("${quote[theQuote]}")
          .setColor("RANDOM") // changed "Random" to "RANDOM" for Discord color
          .setImage(imageQuote[epicQuoteImage])
          .setFooter(`Epic quotes compilation #${compNumber}`);
      
        // After replacing values and adding stuff, it sends the embed...
        interaction.reply({ embeds: [quoting] });
      }
  }
});
```

I know you all know a lot about this API and what not, and I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use simple string in your footer. You have to make object.

**Use this to set your footer:**

```
.setFooter({ text: `Epic quotes compilation #${compNumber}`});
```

[More examples of right embeds you can find in official discord.js guide.](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)

Comment: yes, it works now! I had to set the propertie of the author to name: ,  too but it works now! Thank you so much! 